# Mirror Marketo Data in S3 Bucket for Visualization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, marketo

I am looking to get all of the Activity and Lead data in Marketo to be mirrored in an AWS S3 bucket so that I can build dashboards on it in Quicksight, so preferably I'd like to stream the data from Marketo into S3 in real-time, and then use Glue and Athena to connect the data to Quicksight. However, the only way to get large volumes of data out of Marketo appears to be their [Bulk Extract tool](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/) (one for [Leads](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-lead-extract/), one for [Activity](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-activity-extract/) data).

The problem is that these API interfaces make any attempt at near real-time streaming really clunky. Currently, I have Lambda functions being triggered every hour to pull the most recent hour of Lead/Activity data and saving it as a gzipped CSV in S3. But Marketo's Bulk Extract tool has a request queue and requests often take longer than 15 minutes to process (15 minutes being Lambda's max timeout length). So at least once a day my requests are getting dropped.

The solution seems to be to instead run this on an EC2 instance that can juggle multiple requests and patiently wait for Marketo's queue. But I'd rather not get into all the async and error-handling issues that that approach may entail if there is an easier way to accomplish this.

As an alternative solution, [Amazon Appflow](https://aws.amazon.com/appflow/integrations/) integrates with Marketo. But last I checked, it only works with Lead data, not Activity data. And there are restrictions on the filters you have to apply to the Lead data that make it clunky to work with anyway.

On Google I have found several companies that claim to offer seamless, reliable Marketo-to-S3 ETL, but I haven't yet researched their pricing or quality.

If anyone knows of a good approach to set up reliable and cost-efficient ETL between Marketo and S3 in a short period of time, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I would be tempted to recommend using an EC2 instance to run [Singer](https://www.singer.io/tap/marketo/) with a Marketo input and CSV output, then set up something to move the CSV over to S3 as needed. That would be the absolute cheapest ETL solution, but this does suppose you have some comfort and familiarity with Python.

Also worth noting is that Stitch, Singers's paid product equivalent, supports native S3 export--you could always first test with a non-Marketo data source and see if that performs the way you'd like if you prefer money over time.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I had never heard of Singer, I'll have to check it out. Do you anything about Singer's limitations? I can't find much detail on their website. For example, Amazon AppFlow only lets you access Marketo Lead data (not Activity), and only for a time-span of one month per "flow", and imposes a 20MB data transfer limit per flow, making the service too limited to be an improvement over what I already built on AWS Lambda working directly with Marketo's API.